# phpMyAdmin and mysql not showing the same database

Tags: mysql-5.5, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have setup WAMP which I managed by using a tutorial and everything seems fine... I am logging into mysql as the root user with full privileges granted and I am able to create databases in mysql and view them by using SHOW DATABASES; so far so good !

...However...

[image]

When I access phpMyAdmin and go to the databases section, there are no databases which I have created in mysql, even though phpMyAdmin shows the Database server as User:root@localhost which is the same user I am accessing mysql with.

This situation is also the same when reversed, I can create a database as the root user in phpMyAdmin but the database will not show in mysql when I am logged in as root user and use SHOW DATABASES;

i have tried every soution available ONLINE .. most of them saying about

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '';

i have done that too .... but nothing seems to work.... plzzzz help

Answer (score 1):

The database server that you are accessing using phpmyadmin and the mysql monitor (command line client) are different. If you look at the versions, phpmyadmin is accessing a 5.5.1-m2-community version, while you are accessing 5.6.17-community on the command line.

Either you are accessing a remote server or you have two separate installations of mysql on the server. If the later, use `netstat -aon | more` or the Task Manager to locate the mysql processes running on your machine (and on which port they are listening).